# Parsing Tumblr Json using Retrofit, Gson, and EventBus

Tags: json, gson, tumblr, retrofit2, greenrobot-eventbus

My goal is to extract all the posts from my Tumblr Json data, specifically the post's id, post's url, post tags, post's caption, and post's original size url (photo). A snippet of my Tumblr Json is included below.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "OK"
  },
  "response": {
    "blog": {
      "title": "Materials Library",
      "name": "lunarsf",
      "total_posts": 19,
      "posts": 19,
      "url": "http://lunarsf.tumblr.com/",
      "updated": 1465407313,
      "description": "",
      "is_nsfw": false,
      "ask": false,
      "ask_page_title": "Ask me anything",
      "ask_anon": false,
      "submission_page_title": "Submit",
      "share_likes": true,
      "likes": 0
    },
    "posts": [
      {
        "blog_name": "lunarsf",
        "id": 145616786985,
        "post_url": "http://lunarsf.tumblr.com/post/145616786985/composite-processing-roctool-is-a-tooling-supplier",
        "slug": "composite-processing-roctool-is-a-tooling-supplier",
        "type": "photo",
        "date": "2016-06-08 17:35:12 GMT",
        "timestamp": 1465407312,
        "state": "published",
        "format": "html",
        "reblog_key": "FLjvkWS5",
        "tags": [
          "manufacturing processes",
          "composite processing",
          "Light Induction Tooling",
          "injection molding"
        ],
        "short_url": "https://tmblr.co/Z38G-h27dRzOf",
        "summary": "Composite Processing RocTool is a tooling supplier that has developed Light Induction Tooling (LIT) which allows composite...",
        "recommended_source": null,
        "recommended_color": null,
        "highlighted": [],
        "note_count": 0,
        "caption": "<h2><b>Composite Processing</b></h2><p>RocTool is a tooling supplier that has developed Light Induction Tooling (LIT) which allows composite materials to be molded with the same detail and surface quality as injection molded thermoplastics. The composite layers are placed directly onto the mold and the mold      surface is rapidly heated by an induction system. After the mold is heated, the resin is injected into the tool, quickly cooled by water, and then removed. The process has a cycle time of around 3 minutes depending on the size of the part.</p><p><b>Advantages</b></p><ul><li>Detailed features<br/></li><li>Large or small parts<br/></li><li>High surface quality<br/></li><li>High Volume production<br/></li></ul><p><b>Disadvantages</b></p><ul><li>High unit cost<br/></li><li>Limited suppliers<br/></li></ul>",
        "reblog": {
          "tree_html": "",
          "comment": "<p><h2><b>Composite Processing</b></h2><p>RocTool is a tooling supplier that has developed Light Induction Tooling (LIT) which allows composite materials to be molded with the same detail and surface quality as injection molded thermoplastics. The composite layers are placed directly onto the mold and the mold      surface is rapidly heated by an induction system. After the mold is heated, the resin is injected into the tool, quickly cooled by water, and then removed. The process has a cycle time of around 3 minutes depending on the size of the part.</p><p><b>Advantages</b></p><ul><li>Detailed features<br></li><li>Large or small parts<br></li><li>High surface quality<br></li><li>High Volume production<br></li></ul><p><b>Disadvantages</b></p><ul><li>High unit cost<br></li><li>Limited suppliers<br></li></ul></p>"
        },
        "trail": [
          {
            "blog": {
              "name": "lunarsf",
              "active": true,
              "theme": {
                "avatar_shape": "circle",
                "background_color": "#000000",
                "body_font": "Helvetica Neue",
                "header_bounds": 0,
                "header_image": "https://secure.static.tumblr.com/593bd63829018234cdbbb00fdee3f242/mfeocxi/rRNo74hb0/tumblr_static_5v8qp354ptkww44ococw84c84.jpg",
                "header_image_focused": "https://secure.static.tumblr.com/593bd63829018234cdbbb00fdee3f242/mfeocxi/rRNo74hb0/tumblr_static_5v8qp354ptkww44ococw84c84_2048_v2.jpg",
                "header_image_scaled": "https://secure.static.tumblr.com/593bd63829018234cdbbb00fdee3f242/mfeocxi/rRNo74hb0/tumblr_static_5v8qp354ptkww44ococw84c84_2048_v2.jpg",
                "header_stretch": true,
                "link_color": "#529ECC",
                "show_avatar": true,
                "show_description": true,
                "show_header_image": true,
                "show_title": true,
                "title_color": "#ffffff",
                "title_font": "Helvetica Neue",
                "title_font_weight": "bold"
              },
              "share_likes": true,
              "share_following": false
            },
            "post": {
              "id": "145616786985"
            },
            "content_raw": "<p><h2><b>Composite Processing</b></h2><p>RocTool is a tooling supplier that has developed Light Induction Tooling (LIT) which allows composite materials to be molded with the same detail and surface quality as injection molded thermoplastics. The composite layers are placed directly onto the mold and the mold      surface is rapidly heated by an induction system. After the mold is heated, the resin is injected into the tool, quickly cooled by water, and then removed. The process has a cycle time of around 3 minutes depending on the size of the part.</p><p><b>Advantages</b></p><ul><li>Detailed features<br></li><li>Large or small parts<br></li><li>High surface quality<br></li><li>High Volume production<br></li></ul><p><b>Disadvantages</b></p><ul><li>High unit cost<br></li><li>Limited suppliers<br></li></ul></p>",
            "content": "<p><h2><b>Composite Processing</b></h2><p>RocTool is a tooling supplier that has developed Light Induction Tooling (LIT) which allows composite materials to be molded with the same detail and surface quality as injection molded thermoplastics. The composite layers are placed directly onto the mold and the mold      surface is rapidly heated by an induction system. After the mold is heated, the resin is injected into the tool, quickly cooled by water, and then removed. The process has a cycle time of around 3 minutes depending on the size of the part.</p><p><b>Advantages</b></p><ul><li>Detailed features<br /></li><li>Large or small parts<br /></li><li>High surface quality<br /></li><li>High Volume production<br /></li></ul><p><b>Disadvantages</b></p><ul><li>High unit cost<br /></li><li>Limited suppliers<br /></li></ul></p>",
            "is_current_item": true,
            "is_root_item": true
          }
        ],
        "image_permalink": "http://lunarsf.tumblr.com/image/145616786985",
        "photos": [
          {
            "caption": "",
            "alt_sizes": [
              {
                "url": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_540.jpg",
                "width": 533,
                "height": 400
              },
              {
                "url": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_500.jpg",
                "width": 500,
                "height": 375
              },
              {
                "url": "https://67.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_400.jpg",
                "width": 400,
                "height": 300
              },
              {
                "url": "https://67.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_250.jpg",
                "width": 250,
                "height": 188
              },
              {
                "url": "https://67.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_100.jpg",
                "width": 100,
                "height": 75
              },
              {
                "url": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_75sq.jpg",
                "width": 75,
                "height": 75
              }
            ],
            "original_size": {
              "url": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/802759b5bdb075c3f8f5ce5c482dd448/tumblr_o8griodZwC1v7mn61o1_540.jpg",
              "width": 533,
              "height": 400
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "total_posts": 19
  }
}
```

I am trying to extract this data using Retrofit, Gson, and Eventbus.

Here is my Retrofit builder:

```
package com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.api;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.callbacks.postCallback;
import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.events.PostsReceived;

import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by fongi_000 on 6/11/2016.
 */
public class TumblrAPI{
    private static postCallback TumblrPosts;
    private String API_KEY = "{API_KEY}";
    private static String BASE_URL ="http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/lunarsf.tumblr.com/posts/";

    // Add interceptor when building adapter
    static Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    private static MyAPI service = retrofitAdapter.create(MyAPI.class);

    public static void getTumblrPosts(){

        Call<postCallback> call = service.getPosts();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<postCallback>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<postCallback> call, Response<postCallback> response) {
                Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(response));
                TumblrPosts = response.body();
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new PostsReceived(TumblrPosts));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<postCallback> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("REST",t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is my Retrofit Interface:

```
package com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.api;

import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.callbacks.postCallback;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

/**
 * Created by fongi_000 on 6/11/2016.
 */
public interface MyAPI {

    @GET("photo?&api_key={API_KEY}")
    Call<postCallback> getPosts();
}
```

Here is my PostsReceived.java:

```
package com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.events;

import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.callbacks.postCallback;

/**
 * Created by fongi_000 on 6/11/2016.
 */
public class PostsReceived {

    public postCallback tumblrPosts;
    public PostsReceived(postCallback tumblrPosts) {
        this.tumblrPosts = tumblrPosts;
    }
}
```

And finally here is my Main Activity:

```
package com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.R;
import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.api.TumblrAPI;
import com.example.ianfong.testingretroeventbus.events.PostsReceived;

import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TumblrAPI.getTumblrPosts();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.QR_code_reader);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    public void onEventMainThread(PostsReceived event) {

        Toast mToast_event = Toast.makeText(this,"Event Recognized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast_event.show();

    }

}
```

My POJO was taken from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ after inputting my Tumblr Json.

I am unsure of how to get access to all the different posts on my tumblr blog along with certain information like the url, tags, post photo, etc. One thing to note is that I removed my API Key and replaced it with {API_KEY}.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would love to get input on this if anyone has experience with Retrofit 2, Gson, and Eventbus. Thanks!